# Vim: How do I extract the text of within quotes in a line and paste it at another point in the line without quotes?

Tags: vim

I have a bunch of lines that have this structure:

```
"a": 
"b":
"c":
```

I'd like to change all of the lines so that they have this structure:

```
"a": a
"b": b
"c": c
```

What's the best way to do this in vim?

Comment: There is a dedicated [Vi and Vim Stack Exchange](https://vi.stackexchange.com/), you might have better chances to get an answer there.

Comment: @Katelyn - Is the _text_ only one letter? Do some lines really have a space after the colon, while the others haven't?

Comment: Try `%s/\v"(\w+)":\zs/ \1`

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 1):

In your simple case you can just use visual block selection (similar to multi-cursor):

- press ctrl+v
- move your cursor down
- shift+i
- make changes
- exit Insert mode

Or, what's better -- use macros:

- start recording macro, named `a`: `qa`
- go to the start of the line: `_`
- jump to `"` if necessary: `f"`
- yank everything inside quotes: `yi"`
- move to the line ending and enter insert mode: `A`
- paste from zero register: `ctrl+r 0`
- exit Insert mode: `Esc` (I personally prefer `jk` keybinding for this)
- finish macro recording: `q`

Now just select necessary lines via visual selection `Shift+v`, then type: `:normal @a` to run the macro for each line.

Answer (score 1):

Or you can run the necessary normal mode commands on all lines like so:

```
" note that in the real command, <Esc> would be a literal
" press of the escape key (see explanation below)
:%norm yi"A <Esc>p
```

- apply to the whole file: `%`
- the following normal mode commands: `norm`
- yank inside the double quotes: `yi"`
- append a space to the end of the line: `A`
- escape insert mode (press ctrl+v to enter a literal character, then escape - you'll see a gray symbol appear): ^[
- paste from unnamed register: `p`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use:

```
:%s/"\(.*\)":/\0 \1
```

Explanation:

- `:` run a [command-line mode](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#Command-line) command
- `%` use all lines as the [range](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#%5Brange%5D) of the command
- `s` perform a [substitution](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/change.html#:substitute)
- `/` start the match

  - `"` literal quotes
  - `\(` start a capture group

    - `.*` match any character, zero or more times
  - `\)` end the capture group
  - `":` literal quotes and a colon
- `/` end the match, start the replacement

  - `\0` insert the whole match (e.g. `"a":`)
  - insert a space
  - `\1` insert the contents of the first and only capture group (e.g. `a`)